# Export a CSV file with SQLCMD or BCP, complete columns of Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, export, sqlcmd

That I'm a beginner and I have to export from SQL SERVER Management studio, the result of a query by generating an Excel file, I use either BCP or SQLCMD like this:

```
enter code here
```

exec xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -S localhost -d BaseName -E -Q "SELECT * FROM TableName" -o "c:\MyTest.csv" -W -w 1024 -s"|"'

This is supposed to separate the columns in Excel

My problem is that all the results are placed in the first column and within this column actually columns are separated by the character I entered (here "|"). But I want each column to go in a different column.
I'm beginning to think that this might be possible with BCP or with SQLCMD

would anyone answer?

thank you in advance for reading

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be formatted in Excel using "Text to Columns"

Refer Link: [Text to Columns in Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html)

Answer (score 0):

exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "sp_who" QUERYOUT C:\av\sp_who.txt -S MC0XENTC -T -c '